# Stop environment variables dump in Rails production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a run time error occurs, my Rails app dumps all environment variables in HTTP response, in production. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Which value are you assigning to config.consider_all_requests_local ?

Comment: It's set to false in production. Didn't change it from default in config/environments/production.rb